# Converting VARCHAR to TIMESTAMP with milleseconds yields "ERROR: date/time field value out of range"

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.6, postgresql-10, postgresql-11

I have a VARCHAR column with the value `'2018-07-05T16:14:27.1427'` and I convert it to timestamp with this command:

```
select last_run, 
       to_char(to_timestamp(last_run,'yyyy-MM-dd HH24:mi:ss') - interval '2 hour','yyyy-MM-dd"T"HH24:mi:ss"Z"') as new_last_run 
from schedule_tasks;
```

Until the version 9.6.10 of PostgreSQL, all works good, but now I will migrate to 10.5 and the same command returns ERROR. The same issue happens on PostgreSQL 11.

What I realize is that, on 9.6, the first value of milliseconds when I have 4 digits is added to seconds; for example, `2018-07-05T16:14:27.1427` converted is `2018-07-05T16:14:28.427`.

I don't know if this behavior is normal in the newer versions and I will have to handle it, or if this is a bug.

Comment: Can you have 1427 milliseconds?

Comment: Casting seems to work just fine: `'2018-07-05T16:14:27.1427'::timestamp` But `to_timestamp()` should be told, that there are microseconds: `to_timestamp(last_run, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss.US')`

Comment: But the real question is: why are you storing timestamps in a `varchar` column? If you had chose the correct data type you would not have that problem now.

Comment: So do you have your answer?

Comment: Yes. And the Dev will change the query to compatible with the version 10.

Answer (score 2):

Handling of `date` and `timestamp` input has been made stricter in Postgres 10. [Quoting the release notes:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/release-10.html#id-1.11.6.10.5.8)

> Make [`to_timestamp()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/functions-formatting.html#FUNCTIONS-FORMATTING-TABLE) and `to_date()` reject out-of-range input
>   fields (Artur Zakirov)
>
> For example, previously `to_date('2009-06-40','YYYY-MM-DD')` was
>   accepted and returned `2009-07-10`. It will now generate an error.

Explains what you observed. You'll need to sanitize your input.

Here is the [thread where these changes were discussed](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/flat/CAAJ_b972wbeTjHGg--b4PBSdc-YOY16dyz4q9rc_wA%2BxnF0%2BvQ%40mail.gmail.com#4aeb905d7003c34dcae22293eff3341c).

Answer (score -1):

**Casting seems to work fine with PostgreSQL 11.5**

```
select '2018-07-05T16:14:27.1427', 
       to_char(to_timestamp('2018-07-05T16:14:27.1427','yyyy-MM-dd HH24:mi:ss') - interval '2 hour','yyyy-MM-dd"T"HH24:mi:ss"Z"') as new_last_run
```

Comment: No, this produces `ERROR:  invalid value "T1" for "HH24"`.